# Equivalent of R's googledrive::drive_ls in Python

Tags: python, r, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I need to port some R code to Python and want to list all the files present in a directory which is shared with me. In R I can provide a Drive directory's ID to `googledrive::drive_ls` as per the following:

```r
ID_DIR <- "nprGPfKdhN_LZkyibY9UB43Mzm2D0sCv5"
drive_ls(path = as_id(ID_DIR), type = "spreadsheet")
```

...assuming we have a directory at the URL `https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/nprGPfKdhN_LZkyibY9UB43Mzm2D0sCv5` the ID is `nprGPfKdhN_LZkyibY9UB43Mzm2D0sCv5`. (I randomly generated the ID, so this doesn't actually exist.)

**How can I list all the files present in a directory so as to later use these file IDs to pull in Google Sheets using Python's `gspread`?**

Is there a more direct way to do this using `gspread` without listing the files beforehand?

Comment: In your situation, are these threads useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56857760 https://stackoverflow.com/q/61268195

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Drive API Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) as a reference.

The quickstart lists all the files in the drive.

The part of the list request is the following:

```py
results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])
```

To search the files inside a particular folder you can use the `q` parameter with the `'1234567' in parents` query as mentioned in [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#python).

There is also a Python example in there that shows you how to get the search results to file names and IDs of JPEG image files.